# How to produce audio for tensorflow object detection on the raspberry pi?

Tags: python, audio

I'm trying to add audio output for Tensorflow object detection on the raspberry pi. For example, if it detects a person from the picamera, I'm trying to get the program to say "person". When I use the code below, I get the error message "TypeError: expected str(string), bytes or os". This is likely because I'm assigning the wrong value to speech. What is the right variable/value for the object label?

```
from subprocess import call
```

...

```
speech = classes  
call(["espeak", speech)]
```

Comment: Not Pi specific. It seems to be a general Python question.